# Closest pair points algorithm with Manhattan Distance

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

According to the solution of closet pair (euclid distance) with divide and conquer algorithm during merge algorithm we prove that for each point at distance d (minimum distance of two different sub problem) from line L we just need to check 6 points. But how about Manhattan distance, how many points should we check?

According to below picture, 4 points is it true?[image]

Comment: This would be improved by a more complete description of the algorithm and the problem it is supposed to solve.

Comment: Improved ? Order of the algorithm that I have mentioned is $O(nlogn)$ my question is that checking 4 marked points is enough or my figure is wrong?

Comment: I think, this is answered for all p-norms in the paper "An Optimized Divide-and-Conquer Algorithm for the Closest-Pair Problem in the Planar Case" by Jose C. Pereira and Fernando G. Lobo [2013], or on a reference they give in their paper.